# When do we have $A^3 = 0$ for a $3 \times 3 $ rotation matrix $A$?

Tags: matrices

Let $$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\
\sin \theta &  \cos \theta & 0\\
0& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
Then $A^3=0 \iff $

(a) $\theta =(4k-1)\frac{\pi}{3}$

(b) $\theta =(3k-1)\frac{\pi}{4}$

(c)  $\theta =(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{3}$

(d) none of the above.

I got the (d). I just want to ask that whether I am correct or not?

Comment: $A$ is the matrix of a linear transformation $f$ in a basis $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ which sends $\mathbb{R}u_3$ onto $0$ and rotates vectors $\alpha u_1 + \beta u_2$ by an angle $\theta$. Now, thinking of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, does there exist $n$ such that $e^{in\theta}z = 0$ with $z \neq 0$? (i.e. can you send to $0$ a non-null vector with a rotation ?)

Comment: This is a strange question. I would think that they'd ask about $A^3=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, instead. Also, your rotation matrix isn't a rotation matrix in the usual sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Here's a justification: $A^3$ is the matrix of the rotation of angle $3\theta$ around the $z$-axis:
$$A^3=\begin{bmatrix} \cos3\theta&-\sin 3\theta&0\\
\sin 3\theta&\cos3\theta&0\\
0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
and we can't have both $\cos3\theta=0$ and $\sin3\theta=0$.